# Execute the routine for all elements of the list

Tags: python

I have a list and I need to execute a routine for all elements of the script below:

```
ene = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for i in ene:

        N=int(np.asarray(ene))

        #do the routine
```

I got this:

> IndexError: list index out of range

I need to run this routine for all seven elements of the array ene and save the result of each step (1 to 7).

Ca anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've correctly utilised the `for loop` to iterate over the list, however you are calling the wrong variable to get the data you want. In this case, you should be using `i`

`N=int(np.asarray(i))`

Notice how in the code below, when printing `i` it prints the item it is currently iterating over within the list, however when you print `ene` it prints the entire list.

```
ene = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for i in ene:
    print(i)
    print(ene)


1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
4
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
7
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```